# Auto-Selecting Script Path

Tags: scripting, path

I am still rather new to scripting and powershell. However I have come across a common problem with my scripts. In my deployment environment I mainly deal with Windows 7 and 8. I deploy several programs through the use of a batch file on a USB. I understand that everything could be pushed through the network but I do not have the permissions for that. Now to use the USB method I must make a path for `E:` and a path for `D:` and hope that when the USB was inserted that it received one of those letters or the whole script fails.

Here is an example:

```
Title Installing "Program"  
Echo (Step # of #)  
Echo Installing "Program". . .  
Echo Please Wait. . .  
Echo Attempting Install from D:/  
pushd D:\\Path  
Echo Attempting Install from E:/  
pushd E:\\Path  
Echo Complete  
cls
```

Is there a way for me to condense the path to one line that will pick up `D:`, `E:` or another drive letter? This must also be able to be used on other flash drives as well. Would something like: `.\path` work?

Comment: Is the script on the flash drive as well?

Comment: Yes, the script as well as powershells are.

Answer (score 0):

This depends on the version of pwershell that you are using.  Newer versions will give you the path of the script with `$PSCommandPath`, and you can extract the drive letter using `$PSCommandPath[0]`.

For older versions, you can get the path using `$MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path`, and extract the drive letter with

```
split-path $MyInvocation.MyCommand.Path -Qualifier
```

I would recommend the second method as it will be more portable between different machines that may only have the older version.

If you are runnig this from within a batch file, instead of a powershell script, then `%~do` will give you the drive of the script.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by a command line script.  Do you mean a batch file (.bat extension)?

Comment: Apologies. Yes, the first to run is a batch file that calls to a few different powershells. I will condense them to one PowerShell later.